# nginx replace error 500 with error 503

Tags: nginx, 500-error

I have nginx proxy with backend.

Sometimes the backend return HTTP 500.
In this cases, I want nginx to change the error code from 500 to 503.

Is this possible?

Note: I do not mind to replace "global" 500 error to 503.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031818/show-a-custom-503-page-if-upstream-is-down) gives a couple of options, the simplest of which seems to be:

> Furthermore, it is possible to change the code of answer to another, for  example:
>   `error_page 404 =200 /.empty.gif;`

Or, in your case:

`error_page 500 503 5xx_error.html`

Or something like it.

The docs for `error_page` directive can be found [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page).

Comment: Is it possible to change the error status code without setting a custom page?

Comment: Your example is incorrect it should be `error_page 500 =503 5xx_error.html`.